# TextView setText problem

Tags: android

I'm trying to set text in TextView after geting it from database

```
<TextView 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
    android:text="2510.33" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/so_you_spent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right">
</TextView>
```

This is the activity:

```
public class SummaryOverall extends Activity{

    private CfmDbAdapter db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.summary_overall);

        db = new CfmDbAdapter(this);
        db.open();

        fillData();
    }

    private void fillData() {       
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.so_you_spent);

        Cursor itemCursor = db.fetchAllItemsInOverallSummary();
        if (itemCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String value = itemCursor.getString(0);         
            tv.setText(value);  //nullpointer exception 
        }                   
    }


}
```

It throws NullPointerException at me. Why?

Comment: Check if itemCursor returns what you tell us (321) or not; check if tv is not null.

Comment: We'll need to see all the code. My assumption is that you call fillData() before setContentView

Comment: itemCursor returns "321" but tv is indeed null. Any idea why?

Comment: I think @IncrediApp is right: you call `fillData()` before `setContentView`...

Comment: Tell us the exact source line where debugger complains with `NullPointerException `

Comment: I had to remove android:text="2510.33" line from xml. You can post it as an answer since I can't answer myself yet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check if itemCursor returns what you tell us (321) or not
2. Check if tv is not null

If 1 is true, check db connection or query.
If 2 is true, probably you're using an ID that's not in **summary_overall** layout

**EDITED:**
Try to remove `android:text="2510.33"` line from xml

Comment: 2 is true but as you can see it's not setContentView

Comment: can you post please **summary_overall.xml**?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code----:::

And make sure There were textview id idOk in your xml file....summary_overall

**Remove android:text="2510.33" and set as a android:text=""**

```
private void fillData() {       
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.so_you_spent);

    Cursor itemCursor = db.fetchAllItemsInOverallSummary();
    if (itemCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String value = itemCursor.getString(0); //value taken "321" - string   
        if(value!=null&&value!=""&&tv!=null) {
            tv.setText(value);     
        } else { 
            tv.setText("NO value Found...");     
        }
    }                   
}
```

Comment: same outpout bro. it dies at setText

Comment: I had to remove android:text="2510.33" line from xml. You can post it as an answer since I can't answer myself yet :)